# SqlCommand not inserting into table

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, t-sql

This code seems like it should work, but simply doesn't. I've tried it various ways (with & without SqlDataAdapter)

1. I have both the mdf and xsd selected as "Copy if newer" currently, and have also tried never, and copy always.
2. No errors are thrown when inserted, however if I try to insert a second time, the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_owners'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.owners'. The duplicate key value is (Test).
> The statement has been terminated.

is returned, as if the data is actually in the table.

3. I do have another table & form that does work (not inserts) It is a login table with data I manually inserted (SQL) at the time of table creation, the SQL select statements on that form work perfectly fine (also involve text boxes)

```vb
Private Sub btnInsertOwner_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsertOwner.Click

        Dim db As String = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "VBvetProject.mdf")

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\VBvetProject.mdf;Integrated Security=True;")

        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO owners VALUES (@fullname,@email,@phone,@dob)", conn)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", txtOwnerFullName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtOwnerEmail.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtOwnerPhone.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtOwnerDoB.Text)
            Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            conn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            adapter.Update(dt)
            conn.Close()
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("New owner created!")

    End Sub
```

After attempting to insert a new record from the win form, I check it with a SQL select, and nothing returns (I also expand the table's data through Visual Studio, this is also still null.)

Here is a snip of the table and values:

[image]

I'm honestly at a loss here and could use any help figuring out what I'm doing wrong, this has been such a hair puller.

No matter how many ways I've tried changing the code, the connections, it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You've specified fullname as the primary key, primary keys have to be unique withing a table as per the error message your getting.  Normally you would have what is called a Surrogate Key, which is like an Auto Inc Integer as the Primary Key.  So really, this comes down to how you want your app to work.  Is fullname supposed to be unique?

Comment: DataDirectory shortcut means that the MDF file where database operations happen is located in the BIN\DEBUG subfolder (or BIN\RELEASE) when you debug the program from Visual Studio. Did you check if the MDF in that location contains the first record inserted? (Of course do not use Copy Always otherwise at each run the database is copied to BIN\DEBUG from the empty one in the project folder)

Comment: Suggested reading: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Get rid of your data adapter and your `DataTable`. They are useless in that context. When you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, what value is returned? If it's not zero then the code is working exactly as it should. You should read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsdata/2009/07/30/debugging-with-local-database-file/).